# Angular 10 - CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts

Tags: angular, dependencies, amd, commonjs

I've updated from angular 7.1.4 to 10.
Now i receive strange warnings like this one:

> WARNING in C:\Sviluppo\Welcome\welcome-cloud-app\src\app\calendario-fasce\mese\mese.component.ts depends on src/app/interfaces/calendar/calendar.component. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
> For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

For other warnings like this, i've added in angular.json the relative line, for example:

```
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
    "moment",
    ....
]"
```

How can i resolve this warning relative to my components?

Comment: can  you share the import code of the calendar.component in mese.component.ts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing TS alias might work.

```
import { x } from '@auth/auth....'           // Warning
...to...
import { x } from '../auth/...'              // Warning goes away
```

Refer this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18020) for more

Comment: Hi Arun, the import in MeseComponent is defined like this:
import { CalendarComponent } from 'src/app/interfaces/calendar/calendar.component';

This definition is the same in all my project. VsCode declare it like this by default, i don't think this is the problem.

Comment: I had similar warnings when switching to Angular 10, and while this worked for me as well, I wish I knew why. It seems like a bug if just "finding the module a different way" removes the warning.

Comment: For some reason this has worked for me and fixed my issue