# Angular - primeng CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts

Tags: angular, primeng, angular10

I got a little Angular app, in which I'm using [PrimeNG components](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-4.3.0/#/).
Since I did the Angular 10 update I get the following Warning:

> CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

for different PirmeNg-components.

I already tried this:

```
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "loadsh",
              "primeng/primeng",
              "primeicons",
```

This is suggested on the [offical homepage](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies)

Another try I did is checking the imports like mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593028/angular-10-commonjs-or-amd-dependencies-can-cause-optimization-bailouts)

```
import { x } from '@auth/auth....'           // Warning
...to...
import { x } from '../auth/...'              // Warning goes away
```

But as I don't have any imports with "@" on the beginning I'm wondering how this warning could be fixed or suppressed?

**EDIT:**

Error in detail:

> WARNING in 'path' depends on 'chartjs'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies
> can cause optimization bailouts.

Comment: @Jason Aller Can you share the exact warning message what you are seeing in your build ?

Comment: @GunjanKhanwilkar I didn't ask this question, I only edited it. You want to direct your comment to Felix.

Comment: @Felix Can you share the exact warning message what you are seeing in your build ?

Comment: @GunjanKhanwilkar i added a the Warning as an Edit. 'path' is the excat file of the used library

Comment: @FelixGerber Then you just need to add -
 "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "loadsh",
              "primeng/primeng",
              "primeicons",
              "chartjs"
]
Add chartjs in your existing list like above and you are good. For detailed explanation please check this answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62604034/6097025

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In angular.json add

```
 "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["chart.js"],
```

Comment: It should be "chartjs", not "chart.js". If Jquery, it's also "jquery" not "jQuery.js" or "JQuery".

Comment: Not a fix, just hides the warning. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

you just need to add -

```
    "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [ 
    "loadsh", 
    "primeng/primeng", 
    "primeicons", 
    "chartjs", 
    ---etc--- all the CommonJs dependency goes here to suppress warning!    
]
```

Just Add

> chartjs

in your existing list like above and you are good.
For detailed explanation please check this answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63430362/6097025

Note that this is just a workaround to suppress warnings! If you want to completely fix this then you need to import ES-6 modules for your dependencies and avoid CommonJs dependencies. Angular-10 onwards now it shows these warnings for build optimization.